# Can upload image to SQLite but can extract it again

Tags: database, image, sqlite, png, extract

i have an application where pick photo from library and set it into the UIImageviev in my app.
Then i also save it into SQLite table however can not extract it again by name searching. I know saving method is successful as i control it from Terminal application manually. What is wrong with my extracting method???

```
//Save the photo which is currently in an UIImage Variable into the SQLITE photos as BLOB
-(IBAction)SaveImage{
        sqlite3_stmt *save_statement;
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into photos (name, photo) values(?, ?)"];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_open(dbpath, &photosDB);
        sqlite3_prepare(photosDB, insert_stmt, -1, &save_statement, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(save_statement, 1, [text.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSData *binData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image);
        if (sqlite3_bind_blob(save_statement, 2, [binData bytes], [binData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT)==SQLITE_OK) {
        status.text = @"Gonderi Kaydedildi";}else{status.text = @"Tanimlanamayan bir sorun var";}
        sqlite3_step(save_statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(save_statement);
        sqlite3_close(photosDB);}
```

Below i have some problem...

```
//Get the photo from database construct it and set it into the UIImageView variable in our application
-(IBAction)ImageFromDatabase{

        sqlite3_stmt *call_statement;
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        NSString *findSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT name, photo FROM photos WHERE name=\"%@\"", [text text]];
        const char *sql = [findSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_open(dbpath, &photosDB);
        sqlite3_prepare(photosDB, sql, -1, &call_statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(call_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(call_statement, 0)];
            status.text = imageName;

            const char *rawData = sqlite3_column_blob(call_statement, 2);
            int rawDataLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(call_statement, 2);
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:rawDataLength];
            UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
            image.image = image1;}

        sqlite3_step(call_statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(call_statement);
        sqlite3_close(photosDB);
}
```

I feel that problem is below esspecilly but ?!?!?!?!

```
    const char *rawData = sqlite3_column_blob(call_statement, 2);
    int rawDataLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(call_statement, 2);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:rawDataLength];
    UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    image.image = image1;
```

You saw it???

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry!!! Found the problem and solved it. It was because i was looking at the 2th column instead of 1st...

Answer (score 0):

You're extracting the photo from column 2. To quote the [SQLite reference page](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob);

> The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0

You're only selecting 2 columns, numbered 0 and 1, so your read from column #2 will fail.

In sqlite3_bind_blob the index starts at 1 though, which is why your insert succeeds.